# WordPress: Upload Plugin stuck at "Unpacking the package…", Getting Memory Size Limit Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

I just did a fresh install of WordPress 3.2.1. I've uploaded and activated one plugin with no problem - [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/). I'm attempting to install [Really Simple Captcha](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-simple-captcha/), since it goes along with Contact Form 7.

But, when I go to install it (either upload from my computer or install from WP, doesn't make a difference), it gets stuck at "Unpacking the package...". I check my server error logs, and they have the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 311296 bytes) in <mysite>/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php on line 4186, referer: <mysite>/wp-admin/index.php
```

I've searched this error, and they recommend changing the memory limit to 64m or 128. I tried this, but I still get the same "Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes" error - even though I've changed the memory limit, it still shows the same number.

I've added `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');` to /wp-config.php and to /wp-includes/default-constants.php . I've also added `ini_set("memory_limit","64MB");` to /wp-config.php .

I tried another solution of adding `AddType x-mapp-php5 .php` to .htaccess, but that wouldn't load my site - gave me error `[warn] Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'`

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: Changing `php.ini` settings (which you seemingly didn't actually do) has no effect unless you restart the server. Sigh, that AddType will only work if you actually have a dual PHP4/PHP5 setup and configured that precise action name (unlikely that it pertains to your server). And you should rather look into the `class-simplepie.php on line 4186` as mentioned by the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the first two answers. As for looking into `class-simplepie.php on 4186`, that code is not the issue here, that is generic WordPress code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/memory_limit) in the `php.ini` for your server. Changing it at runtime has typically no effect (on shared hosting anyway), much less the `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` constant.

If `safe_mode` and other restrictions are not enabled, then `php_value` via `.htaccess` or in a `.user.ini` for CGI setups might work.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem solved with disabling "JCH OPTIMIZE" Plugin