# unpacking the package in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, server, hosting

Hi in my WordPress site an issue is not resolve unpacking the package in wordpress

my server not able to unzip any file fetch from other server..

i try all way to increase my memory limit via php.ini .user.ini , wp-config.php and last .htacess and its show via server status that all have sufficient value

but still when i install any plugin its stuck in unpacking

```
my server status

Server info:        Apache
PHP version:        5.6.31
PHP post max size:      96 MB
PHP time limit:     600
PHP max input vars:     1000
cURL version:       7.53.1, OpenSSL/1.0.2k
SUHOSIN installed:      –
Max upload size:        96 MB
WP version:     4.8.1
WP multisite:       –
WP memory limit:        500 MB
WP debug mode:      
WP cron:        
Language:       en_US
```

only show this

```
Installing Theme: Cian - App Landing Page WordPress 2.0
Downloading install package from the Envato API…

Unpacking the package…
```

is this hosting problem if yes then what I say to host provider to do an update to make working this ??

Comment: what the error can you post it ?

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez its no unpack any plugin Which is in large size likie WooCommerce and don't get any error

Comment: try to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439375/wordpress-upload-plugin-stuck-at-unpacking-the-package-getting-memory-size?rq=1

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez already try not get any help from this